# How to do a tumblr like grid in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image, grid

After spending all day long trying to found how to make a nice tumblr-like grid for my website, I'm posting here to find help.
here's the page: http://alexis.gargaloni.free.fr/main.html
In order to access to my project there's a grid of images displayed. At the moment it looks OK, but now that I need to add something new, it starts to look really bad. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qh4k.png)
As you can see, there's a white gap. I've tried many things and there's every time a gap (even when it's not supposed to be there).
Here's an example of what I want to achieve: http://alexgargaloni.tumblr.com

here's my HTML code (included filter):

```
    <div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> TOUT</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('imprime')"> IMPRIMÉ</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('digital')"> NUMERIQUE</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('picture')"> PHOTO</button>
</div>
<div class="pic"> <a href="ego_graphique.html"><img class="filterDiv picture" src="images/ego5-4.jpg" alt="ego graphique" style="width:40% "> </a> <a href="institut_poincare.html"><img class="filterDiv imprime" src="images/ihp1_1.jpg" alt="affiches pour l'institut henri poincaré" style="width:25%"> </a> <a href="jpo_gat_17.html"><img class="filterDiv imprime" src="images/jpogat17.png" alt="portes ouvertes lycée du gué à tresmes 2017" style="width:25%"></a><a href="details_et_des_tailles.html"><img class="filterDiv imprime" src="images/detailbook1.jpg" style="width:35%"></a> <a href="experience_de_la_duree.html"><img class="expav filterDiv digital" src="images/expavstatic.png" alt="expérience de la durée" style="width:35%" ></a></div>
```

and CSS:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;

}

body {
background: white;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
line-height: 25px;
margin: 0 0 900px; /* bottom = footer height */
padding: 25px;
}

    .img{

    margin: 20px;
}

/* FILTER */    
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.filterDiv {
    float:left;
    /*color: #ffffff;*/
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 13px;
    display:none; /* Hidden by default */

}

.show {
    display: block;

}
.pic
{

      max-width: 100%;
}
```

I'm new to HTML and CSS, and I know that my code is not a 100% clean and it could be way more simplified, but I'm working on it.
Excuse my English, I'm French

Thank for your help!

EDIT @ben_fluleck

Thank you. There’s a problem with “height: 100%”, because it modifies the aspect ratio of my pic. If I change height and width with max-width and max-height, the white gap is back. I also need to keep “display: none” on. filterDiv to make the filter function work (something with javascript). And also I’m having a problem with filter now, it still works, but pics are not getting how they’re supposed to (before:[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bRFE.png) after:[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NvfQ.png), it's like elements filtered create a white space instead of disappearing). I’ve tried to do something with the tumblr html, but it didn’t seem to work. Simple things are super tricky to do… I really need something that trick the size itself like tumblr theme, because when I’ll ad new things on my website, I feel like it’s going to be a mess again.
Yes, my footer is not really well implemented, I’ve checked online a way to make it because it’s really tricky, and how I did was the only way I was able to make it work. Thank a lot for you help! We can see the footer later, for the moment I really need to focus on this grid

Comment: use bootstrap or flexbox

Comment: I'm a bit confused with html kit such as bootstrap, I'm new to html so things don't seems obvious to me. I've also seen Masonry that seems really nice, but I don't understand how to use it properly

Answer (score 0):

Try these CSS Layouts they will get your pics in order

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

set a viewport height in the body and work of that

```
body{
background: white;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
line-height: 25px;
/* margin: 0 0 900px; */
padding: 25px;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.pic {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
grid-gap: 10px;
}

.filterDiv {
float: left;
width: 100%;
line-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
height: 100%; /*optional if you want them to be all the same same */
}

.show {
/* display: block; */
}
```

Comment: I just replied above (new here, don't know where to make a comment with pic ...)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the picture in my Css above should be pic since you have named them you can constrain the pics giving them a width property. I would remove the inline styling for width and use percentages in the Css.

I have constructed a fiddle you could expand upon but it should give you a better idea of the layout.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  }

.box {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Colours for each box */

.box1 {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.box2 {
  background: #3498db;
}

.box3 {
  background: #9b59b6;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLjuLjoc/1/

Comment: Thank for your help but I'm still having the same issue. And even if I use "flex-basis: 400px;" (or flex: 1 1 400px;), it seems like nothing is happening. There still is a problem about the size, which I think, is linked to the white gap between the first and second row images

Comment: Ok I decided to inspect the website on my pc using chrome dev tools and it is a bit interesting. I'd say careful with the body and how you set your initial margins up as they nuisance. I am going to put up a new answer with my edits.

Comment: modified below, tell me if it is something you want i can explain how you can implement the footer as you have placed it wrongly.

Comment: Perhaps you can do a jsfiddle i feel the javascript needs to be examined as well. Failing that if there is a way to contact you over zoom or slack I can have a look at the codebase.

Comment: Ok I don't have any account on these but it'll be easier. Let's do with slack, do I have to create a workspace or join yours?